# Using Hibernate "thread" session context in production

Tags: java, hibernate

[This page](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/tutorial.html) from the Hibernate tutorial on jboss.org says:

> Hibernate offers three methods of current session tracking. The "thread" based method is not intended for production use; it is merely useful for prototyping and tutorials such as this one.

I haven't been able to find any other sources indicating one way or the other.
Is this true? If so, why, and is it still true for Hibernate 4.x? And what context sessions are intended for production use?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate supports these session management options:

- (jta) org.hibernate.context.JTASessionContext: current sessions are tracked and scoped by a JTA transaction. The processing here is exactly the same as in the older JTA-only approach.
- (thread) org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext:current sessions are tracked by thread of execution.
- (managed) org.hibernate.context.ManagedSessionContext: current sessions are tracked by thread of execution. However, you are responsible to bind and unbind a Session instance with static methods on this class: it does not open, flush, or close a Session.

See: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userGuide/en-US/html_single/#architecture-current-session

Older implementations that used Hibernate directly often use a "thread per session" model even though they aren't recommended now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this isn't really what I was asking.  I'm well aware there are 3 types of session management, and the documentation says 1 of them, the thread type, is not for production use.  I wanted alternative sources for this info, or an explanation with a source.